# WooCommerce set product dimensions (width & height) based on single attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dimensions

The Shop is selling framed images. The customer can chose *frame material* and *dimensions (list of preset Width x Height combinations)*. Both – *frame material* and *dimensions* are configured as predefined Attribute Lists. For Dimensions only some very specific Width x Height combinations are available. See Example:

[image: Example Attribute Lists]

Then the option [Create variations from all attributes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/#section-7) is used to have WooCommerce generate every possible combination of these variations. So we end up with a list like this:

[image: Example for generated Variations]

The critical Point is, that now we need the 2 standard meta fields *Width* & *Height* for every variation to be filled in some way **automatically** based on the selected Dimension custom Attribute. Like this:

[image: Example of needed Functionality]

So basically (no real code):

```
if (selected Dimensions Attribute is "30 x 20 cm") set meta $width = 30 & meta $height = 20 
if (selected Dimensions Attribute is "45 x 30 cm") set meta $width = 45 & meta $height = 30 
if (selected Dimensions Attribute is "60 x 40 cm") set meta $width = 60 & meta $height = 40 
etc.
```

It would be enough if this happens, when the variable product is saved/updated. The solution can be pretty simplistic, since the Attribute List for Dimensions is predefined.

I know this might be a somewhat special case, but I think the needed functionality might be of interest for others too.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this following code fills the width and height when the variation is saved :

```
add_action("woocommerce_before_product_object_save", function ($product, $data_store) {

    if ("variation" !== $product->get_type()) {
        return;
    }


    $abmessung = $product->get_attribute("abmessung-3-2"); // use the text "60 x 40 cm"
    $parse = explode(" ", $abmessung);

    $product->set_props([
        "width" => $parse[0],
        "height" => $parse[2],
    ]);


}, 10, 2);
```